# How to move Inbound Multipart form-data file from tmp directory

Tags: php, apache2, webhooks

I am writing a webhook to receive inbound faxes. The inbound POST makes it to the server. The problem is retrieving the attachments to the post. My error log has this message.

```
 PHP Warning:  copy(/tmp/php4qL9du/pdf-sample.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

The array that is in the $_FILES is this

```
Array
(
  [attachment] => Array
    (
        [name] => pdf-sample.pdf
        [type] => application/pdf
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phppw5aIU
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 7945
    )

)
```

I put the array into variables.

```
 $inboundFaxDocumentName = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
 $inboundFaxLocation = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
 $inboundFaxFilesize = $_FILES['attachment']['size'];
 $local = $inboundFaxLocation."/".$inboundFaxDocumentName;
 copy($local, "/var/www/html/new_home/");
```

I thought I would go ahead and show what I have for headers on this inbound webhook

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset-UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorizations, X-Requested-With");
```

I have tried to manually go look for the file. I have not been able to find any file. I am not sure what else I can do to troubleshoot this situation. Any suggestions for troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should add a separate Answer, if you wish to give more info about the solution. Answers are not part of the question :-). Just because you accepted my answer doesn't mean you can't add a supplementary one.

Comment: I will do that in the future. I have seen other posts done that way is the reason that I have been doing so. Thank you.

Comment: Other posts should not be doing that either! They might occasionally resort to it if the question has been closed (and thus not allowing any answers to be posted), but it's a problem because the information does not show as a solution when you are searching (via google or via stackoverflow's search), so people searching with similar problems or searching for a similar solution might not find it. That's why the site is strictly divided into questions and answers sections, rather than a more linear forum-like structure,.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and other can follow this to make the whole site better for everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just

```
$local = $inboundFaxLocation;
```

`$_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']` should already contain a full path to the temporary file, there's no need to add the original name as well.

P.S. Normally in PHP people use `move_uploaded_file()` specifically for the purpose of transferring an uploaded file from its temporary uploaded location to a more permanent one - there's no point in copying really, because the temp file will be removed anyway after a period of time when the script ends.

Answer (score 1):

Final code that worked for me.

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], "/var/www/html/new_home/" . $_FILES['attachment']['name']);
```